# Trying to propagate an event to a custom HTML element from one of its components throws

Tags: javascript, exception, ecmascript-6, custom-element

I'm trying to make a control allowing the user to set a value both through a numeric input and through a slider. Having read the [relevant docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements), this is what I came with:

```js
class NumberAndRange extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
  
        this.number = document.createElement('input')
        this.number.type = 'number'
        this.range = document.createElement('input')
        this.range.type = 'range'
  
        this.number.addEventListener('input',
            ()=>{this.range.value = this.number.value}
        )
        this.range.addEventListener('input',
            ()=>{this.number.value = this.range.value}
        )
  
        shadow.appendChild(this.number)
        shadow.appendChild(this.range)
    }
}
customElements.define('number-and-range', NumberAndRange)
```

```html
<number-and-range></number-and-range>
```

As you can see, it works (at least in browsers that support this). For brevity, I skipped the code that makes sure that setting the `min`, `max`, `step` etc attributes on `numeric-and-range` also sets them on both `input`s and that reading these attributes from `numeric-and-range` returns meaningful results.

However, there is one functionality I'm not able to add. Clearly, we would like that triggering an `input` event on both `numeric` and `range` would also trigger this event on `numeric-and-range`; so that we may forget that `numeric-and-range` actually consists of two inputs and instead treat it as if it was a single control. Therefore:

```js
class NumberAndRange extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
  
        this.number = document.createElement('input')
        this.number.type = 'number'
        this.range = document.createElement('input')
        this.range.type = 'range'
  
        this.number.addEventListener('input',
            ()=>{this.range.value = this.number.value}
        )
        this.range.addEventListener('input',
            ()=>{this.number.value = this.range.value}
        )
    
        const whole = this
        this.number.addEventListener('input',
            (ev)=>{whole.dispatchEvent(ev)}
        )
        this.range.addEventListener('input',
            (ev)=>{whole.dispatchEvent(ev)}
        )
  
        shadow.appendChild(this.number)
        shadow.appendChild(this.range)
    }
}
customElements.define('number-and-range', NumberAndRange)
```

```html
<number-and-range></number-and-range>
```

But this doesn't work! For reasons beyond my coprehension moving the slider throws. `InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable` Which object is not usable? And why would it not be usable? I'm staring at my code and can't really find any mistake.

Could you enlighten me what am I doing wrong?

Edit: The idea suggested in the comments doesn't seem to work for me either:

```js
class NumberAndRange extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        const whole = this
        this.number.addEventListener('input',
            (ev)=>{whole.dispatchEvent(ev)}
        )
        this.range.addEventListener('input',
            (ev)=>{whole.dispatchEvent(ev)}
        )
    }

    constructor() {
        super()
        const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
  
        this.number = document.createElement('input')
        this.number.type = 'numeric'
        this.range = document.createElement('input')
        this.range.type = 'range'
  
        this.number.addEventListener('input',
            ()=>{this.range.value = this.number.value}
        )
        this.range.addEventListener('input',
            ()=>{this.number.value = this.range.value}
        )
  
        shadow.appendChild(this.number)
        shadow.appendChild(this.range)
    }
}
customElements.define('number-and-range', NumberAndRange)
```

```html
<number-and-range></number-and-range>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the code in `connectedCallback ` method instead. I would not recommend attaching or appending in the constructor

Comment: @Pavlo Thank you for your comment, though I'm not sure if I understand what you mean :( "*Have you tried putting the code in connectedCallback method instead.*" - **if** you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/t321hke8/ then unfortunately it doesn't work :( "*I would recommend attaching or appending in the constructor*" - I think I'm doing this already? I call `shadow.appendChild(this.numeric)` in the constructor and not anywhere else?

Comment: I am not really sure, in the JSFiddle everything works fine for me

Comment: @Pavlo I've put this fiddle in the OP as well, could you check if this is still working fine here? Sorry if that's not the case, but JSFiddle doesn't display errors as prominently as fiddles on Stackoverflow, have you checked if your browser console was spitting any errors? Because I double-checked and I'm still seeing errors, both on JSFiddle and here :(

Comment: Only dispatchEvent saying that event is already being dispatched. I am on Google Chrome

Comment: @Pavlo Ooh can I not redispatch an event? Maybe that's the cause? Well I'm on Firefox, maybe Firefox means the same but produces a less precise error?

Comment: Okay by removing the dispatchEvent it works without any errors `https://jsfiddle.net/ktjrLyq8/` also i just learned about about:config and manually enabling customElements, thanks!

Comment: @Pavlo Of course by removing the dispatchEvent it works without any errors, but, well... this is kind of pointless without dispatchEvent since the needed functionality is not there. Anyway, you did point me at the (hopefully) correct solution (see answer), thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Pavlo for pointing out the problem: events cannot be redispatched. Therefore the solution is to create a new event instead:

```js
class NumberAndRange extends HTMLElement {
    // Handling of the value attribute should probably be done better
    // quick and dirty here
    get value() {return this.number.value}

    constructor() {
        super()
        const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
  
        this.number = document.createElement('input')
        this.number.type = 'number'
        this.range = document.createElement('input')
        this.range.type = 'range'
  
        this.number.addEventListener('input',
            ()=>{this.range.value = this.number.value}
        )
        this.range.addEventListener('input',
            ()=>{this.number.value = this.range.value}
        )
    
        const whole = this
        this.number.addEventListener('input',
            ()=>{whole.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))}
        )
        this.range.addEventListener('input',
            ()=>{whole.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))}
        )
  
        shadow.appendChild(this.number)
        shadow.appendChild(this.range)
    }
}
customElements.define('number-and-range', NumberAndRange)
```

```html
<number-and-range oninput="console.log(this.value)"></number-and-range>
```

Answer (score 0):

You already found your problem that Events can't be re-dispatched.

But you don't need to dispatch **any** Custom Event,   use the default `oninput` event

http://jsfiddle.net/dannye/6zk4vgc0

```
class NumberAndRange extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    let input = ['number','range'].map(
      (type, idx) => 
      Object.assign(
        this.appendChild(document.createElement('input')),
        { 
          type, 
          min : 20,
          max : 50,
          value : 42,
          oninput : _ => input[~~!idx].value = input[idx].value
        }))
  }
}
customElements.define('number-and-range', NumberAndRange);
```

note: `~~!idx` is the same as `idx == 0 ? 1 : 0`, just some bytes shorter